# How to make a method const based on the template parameter?

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class with a template parameter, and I want to call a method of it. It looks something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        for (auto& t: ts) {
            t.doSomething();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> ts;
};
```

This works, but I want to make `doSomething()` const if `T` itself is const (it is assumed that `T::doSomething()` will be const too). I found a possible solution (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001599/c-enable-method-based-on-boolean-template-parameter)), but I don't like it.

```
template <bool enabled = std::is_const<T>::value>
typename std::enable_if<enabled, void>::type
doSomething() const {
    for (auto& t: ts) {
        t.doSomething();
    }
}

template <bool enabled = !std::is_const<T>::value>
typename std::enable_if<enabled, void>::type
doSomething() {
    for (auto& t: ts) {
        t.doSomething();
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it has a code duplication. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: As a workarround you could add `private: attribute(always_inline) _doSomething` and call that from your `(const) dosomething`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not perfect here is a workaround: we have a non const member `_doSomething()` where we have the code that is the same for const and non const, except the function called on the underlying object. Since this member is `non const` we have to `const_cast` `this` to call it from a const Foo.

Since the code inside `_doSomething` is const safe, it is safe to (const_)cast `const` away.

Your code also will not compile for const, since you can not have a `vector` of `const`. A vector's elements must be assignable, which `const types` are *typically* not (they really should not, however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313104/258418).
You might want to consider `std::vector<T*>` rather than `std::vector<T>`. (I.e. store pointers rather than the objects in the vector)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {}
    void doSomething() const {
        std::cout << "const" << endl;
    }

    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "NON const" << endl;
    }
};


template <typename T>
class Foo {
    void _doSomething() {
        /*for (auto& t: ts) {
            t.doSomething();
        }*/
        test.doSomething();
    }
public:
    Foo()/*T element) : ts({element})*/ {}

    template <bool enabled = std::is_const<T>::value>
    typename std::enable_if<enabled, void>::type
    doSomething() const {
        const_cast<typename std::remove_const<Foo<T>>::type*>(this)->_doSomething();
    }

    template <bool enabled = !std::is_const<T>::value>
    typename std::enable_if<enabled, void>::type
    doSomething() {
        _doSomething();
    }
private:
    //std::vector<T> ts; https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313104/258418
    T test;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar> nonConstInst;
    Foo<const Bar> ConstInst;

    nonConstInst.doSomething();
    ConstInst.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: True, it doesn't work for vector. In reality I'm using `shared_ptr` there (`unique_ptr` would be better), so the const function would always work. Still, the contained objects are part of the state of the object, so I want `doSomething()` to be non-const if I am changing the state of the contained objects. But anyway your solution works and I didn't even have to `const_cast`.

Comment: • Isn't `typename std::remove_const<Foo<T>>::type*` just `Foo<T>*`? What's the difference? (unless you want to do `typename std::remove_const<decltype(*this)>::type*` to be generic, but I don't see the point)

Comment: Remark: const_cast a originally const object is actually safe as long as no attempt is made to modify it. It's definitely dangerous however. [c++ - Is it allowed to cast away const on a const-defined object as long as it is not actually modified? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504247/is-it-allowed-to-cast-away-const-on-a-const-defined-object-as-long-as-it-is-not)